# Version Control with Google Docs Best Practices?

Tags: version-control, google-docs

From a quick perusal, it seems that Google Docs does not support version control the way git or svn does.  My question is:

If I want to store all my documents on Google Docs, what is the best way to make them be capable of branch/merge type version control?  What would this require?

Or what is the workflow you use to store your families/companies documents on Google Docs and sync them with git/svn so multiple people can be editing a document concurrently and they won't overwrite changes?

Comment: The webapps site seems like a better place for this question.  See my related question there: [Import google docs document revision history into a git repository?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/25592/import-google-docs-document-revision-history-into-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to write an application to do that. Read some google docs protocol documentation, specially [Document Revisions](http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#RevisionHistory) section. Be aware though that this is going to be a lot of work: you would need an application that compares all the data from your revisions in google docs to your git/svn ones and vice versa.

Seriously, having already a SCM configuration, I would stick to it, and do a simple python script that would "export" the last docs commits (or tags) to my google docs. This way you can read your documentation anywhere (you just need a browser) but still having the benefits of a traditional SCM, being this a best-of-both-worlds approach IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about google docs... but have you looked at [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)? I have used that on a couple small to medium sized projects and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Code. Google Docs is rather rudimentary. It doesn't have Word's versioning features. You can save many revisions however.